# What's the difference between `verifySequence` and `verifyOrder` in MockK?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

In the guide for MockK library, the example is not clearing this for me. Here follows the example from the documentation:

```
class MockedClass {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

val obj = mockk<MockedClass>()
val slot = slot<Int>()

every {
    obj.sum(any(), capture(slot))
} answers {
    1 + firstArg<Int>() + slot.captured
}

obj.sum(1, 2) // returns 4
obj.sum(1, 3) // returns 5
obj.sum(2, 2) // returns 5

verifyAll {
    obj.sum(1, 3)
    obj.sum(1, 2)
    obj.sum(2, 2)
}

verifySequence {
    obj.sum(1, 2)
    obj.sum(1, 3)
    obj.sum(2, 2)
}

verifyOrder {
    obj.sum(1, 2)
    obj.sum(2, 2)
}

val obj2 = mockk<MockedClass>()
val obj3 = mockk<MockedClass>()
verify {
    listOf(obj2, obj3) wasNot Called
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method `verifySequence` checks that only the specified calls happened and this must be in the same order. Method `verifyOrder` on the other hand also works if you leave out some calls as you already did in the example (`obj.sum(1, 3)`). The following will fail because you cannot leave out a call with `verifySequence`:

```
verifySequence {
    obj.sum(1, 2)
    obj.sum(2, 2)
}
```